# Converting hexadecimal string to utf8 doesn't work from a chunk in node.js

Tags: node.js, utf-8, hex

I am working with some data in node which has been stored in a database after being converted from a normal text string to a hex one.

When I get this data back I can log the hex value in the console and check it on a site like [this](http://string-functions.com/hex-string.aspx) and it works however when I run it through what I think should convert it, it gives me nothing.

It does work however if I manually enter the string (and not get it from the chunk in the web request).

This works:

```
  var hex = "7b226461746574696d65223a22323031372d30372d31325432303a35323a34342e3432395a222c226465636973696f6e223a227061727479227d";
  var hexData = new Buffer(hex, 'hex').toString('utf8');
  console.log(hexData);
```

However this does not:

```
  var hex = chunk.toString();
  console.log(hex); // outputs "7b226461746574696d65223a22323031372d30372d31325432303a35323a34342e3432395a222c226465636973696f6e223a227061727479227d"
  var hexData = new Buffer(hex, 'hex').toString('utf8');
  console.log(hexData);
```

Even though I can see the data is the same in the console output

Comment: What is inside of `chunk`?

Comment: It's the response from a http request, when just outputted it gives me a buffer

Comment: Why are you converting `chunk` (a Buffer) to a hex string, only to convert it back to a Buffer again (and then to a utf8 string)?

Comment: Could you show what is inside of that? Just print it.

Comment: It print's out as <Buffer 22 37 62 32 32 36 34 36 31 37 34 36 35 37 34 36 39 36 64 36 35 32 32 33 61 32 32 33 32 33 30 33 31 33 37 32 64 33 30 33 37 32 64 33 31 33 32 35 34 33 ... >

Comment: I was converting chunk to buffer and back in an attempt to get it to work. When I just use chunk.toString('utf8') I still just get the hex string output and not text